# Migrate subsite to new sharepoint install

Tags: migration, sub-site

I'm sure this is simple but I'd like to make sure I'm following best practice here. I have an old SharePoint 2013 environment (let's just call it SP-A) that has a subsite for IT in it. I'd like to move that entire subsite to my new SharePoint deployment (SP-B). How, or what is the best way to accomplish this? It's not terribly large and has maybe 20-30 word/excel documents, a calendar, and some small stuff. What's the best way to go about moving the subsite from SP-A to the new SP-B?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any workflows, event receivers or other customisations on the site that need to be moved? Or is just a few lists of data?

Comment: Nothing, just the lists/data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one thing make sure before start the process. You SP-A and SP-B should be on the same SharePoint Version level( same build number and CU level).

If SP-A is higher then SP-B then you are out of luck.

If both are same then you can do two way.

**Save As template**
 - Save the Sub-site as template( if not a publishing site) with option of include the content.
 - Then Download the file and upload to the SP-B site collection
 - Now Create the Sub site using that template.
 - Read more over here :
   https://support.office.com/en-us/article/save-a-sharepoint-site-as-a-template-5a4eb024-d1fa-4681-a4ac-e6bd1e3209ba?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1

**Using the Import And Export method**

- Run the [Export-spweb](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607895.aspx) on the SP-A farm
- Move the backup file to SP-B
- Now run the [Import-Spweb](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607613.aspx).

Comment: Where can I check the version (build and CU level)?

Comment: SP-A = 15.0.4667.1000
SP-B = 15.0.4617.1000 (don't ask me how this is older even though it's the new one)

Comment: Ok, then you can't restore it from SP-A to B as you will get version mismatch. Or upgrade B to same level